# Build kernel with multi_v7_defconfig setting

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

What is multi_v7_defconfig used for and how do I build the Linux kernel with this?
I think I can write this into config file as:

```
CONFIG_multi_v7_defconfig=y
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that's a target you can instruct `make` to use which enlists a "set" of actual kernel configs.

```
$  make multi_v7_defconfig
```

The list of the configs that will get used is here:

- http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/configs/multi_v7_defconfig

#### References

- [Xen ARM with Virtualization Extensions/Allwinner](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_ARM_with_Virtualization_Extensions/Allwinner)